# Is there any configuration to run docker inside a jenkins container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-container, jenkins-agent

I am trying to build an image with docker and then upload it to the docker hub, after passing the quality tests I receive the following error: docker: not found, how can I communicate my docker service (localhost) with the container of Jenkins.

**Important:** I have docker desktop installed locally and I have installed Jenkins in a local container also in Windows 10 pro.

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIvj1.jpg
Pipeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6YTr.jpg

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please don't put link to images, upload the images to the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to do this:

1. Install Docker inside your Jenkins Container and also add a bind mount for the Docker socket from your host. Otherwise your Docker Daemon inside your Container wont work. On Linux this socket is `/var/run/docker.sock`, so the bind mount would look like `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`.
2. Use a different slave agent for the `Building Image` Stage where you have docker installed. For e.g. you could use Docker-in-Docker (https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) as a Slave Agent for Jenkins (connected via ssh) and run your docker build inside this slave agent.

Comment: What do you mean by "Jenkins Machie"? Do you mean your Jenkins (Master) Container configuration?